# How to display output of long running program using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am wanting to run a long running process on a server and have the output go (in real-time) to a page open in my browser.

I've got this so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Hello World</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#msgid").html("This is Hello World by JQuery");
$.get('runner.php', function (data) {
  $('#result').html(data);
});
});

</script>

This is Hello World by HTML

<div id="msgid">
</div>
<div id="result">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It appears to run my script, but I'm not seeing any output. For testing you can just have runner.php do a tail -F of a log file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please review for on-topic?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track! You can have a JS function that will poll for updates and update the content accordingly.

```
$.get('/api/my-long-running-process', function (data) {
  $('#result').html(data);
});
```

Then on your server, you need an endpoint (here `/api/my-long-running-process`) that returns the current output of your script. Now the way you retrieve the output depends on where the output is stored. If it's a file, your server can simply return the content of this file.

Comment: Thanks, my process will just run and I'm interested in displaying the output from it (stdout). Simple.

Comment: I tried incorporating this into my small example above, not working... If I point my browser to my runner.php script, it runs and gives me output. However, it never stops...

Comment: You need to poll for data and need a way to tell your JS that there is no more data. Instead of returning the plain output, you can wrap it in a JSON object: `{isFinished: false, output: "..."}` and keep polling until isFinished is true. If you wrap your `$.get()` call inside a setInterval(), you can achieve this.

Comment: Actually, the script will never actually finish. I have a check to see if the connection has been aborted (so I stop when there isn't anything connected to it any more). What would the setInterval look like above?